# How to find a max of a list inside a dataframe inside a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

I am trying to print inside a DataFrame the results of the lost function and accuracy. However, I want to keep only the max validation accuracy for all epochs per iteration. So if i have 2 iterations of 3 epochs, I want to keep only 2 rows.

```
#Hyperparameters
lr = [0.001,0.005,0.01,0.02]
bs = [25,50,75,100]
neurons=[8,10,12]
optimizer=['keras.optimizers.Adam','keras.optimizers.SGD','keras.optimizers.RMSprop']

results = []

for x in range(2):

  lr_rand=random.choice(lr)
  bs_rand=random.choice(bs)
  opt_rand=random.choice(optimizer)
  neu_rand=random.choice(neurons)

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
  model.add(Dense(neu_rand, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(neu_rand, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(neu_rand, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
  
  model.summary()
  
  model.compile(loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer=eval(opt_rand)(learning_rate=lr_rand),
                metrics=[keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy])
  hy=model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, batch_size=bs_rand, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_valid_scaled, y_valid))
  
  pd.DataFrame(hy.history).plot(figsize=(16, 8), ls='-')
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1.01)
  plt.title("Lost Function and Accuracy for training and validation: Learning rate:{:3.1f}%, {}, Batch Size: {}, Neurons : {}".format(lr_rand*100,opt_rand,bs_rand,neu_rand))
  plt.show()
```

When I print that code, I will get 2 grid of 3 epochs ( i put 3 epochs only to simplify the running time until i get the answer of my question. So obviously i will increase it once i find the solution to my question).

i tried to add that to my code but it doesn't work

```
results.append(hy.history)
  results = pd.concat(results)
results
```

so i tried to understand how it is working.
when i use that code:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

i get

[image]

So i was wondering how to get the max value of a list inside a dataframe. I would like to see only 1 value per CELL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to add a few lines of code, as shown below, to do that.

```
    iteration_hist = hy.history
    max_accuracy_index = np.argmax(iteration_hist['accuracy'])
    results.append(pd.DataFrame({"loss":[iteration_hist["loss"][max_accuracy_index]],
                                 "sparse_categorical_accuracy": [iteration_hist["sparse_categorical_accuracy"][max_accuracy_index]],
                                 "val_loss": [iteration_hist["val_loss"][max_accuracy_index]],
                                 "val_sparse_categorical_accuracy": [iteration_hist["val_sparse_categorical_accuracy"][max_accuracy_index]]
                                }))
```